# Enlistar registro duplicado en vista Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo la siguiente duda, tengo el siguiente código

```
foreah($Ruc as $key => $R){
   $RucEE = client::where('Ruc',"=",$R)->first();
   if($RucEE != null){
     
   }else{
     echo '<b>'.$R.'</b><br>';
   }
return view ('facturacion.create');
```

El cual me imprime los registro faltando haciendo una validación... el problema es que no sé cómo pasarlo correctamente a la vista... me estaría imprimiendo de esta manera [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera imprimirlo en un Alert debajo de facturación gracias de antemano por quien me pueda ayudar

Comment: Para mostrar los datos debes enviarlos a la plantilla correspondiente (en este caso veo que es facturación.create). Luego en la propia plantilla recorres el array donde te interese y lo pintas como te interese. Revisa en la doc de laravel el tema de plantillas blade

Comment: Hola que tal gracias por responderme, ya he intentado lo que me indicas pero al hacerlo no me hace la validación simplemente me trae todos $Ruc y no me valida ninguno.. gracias por responderme de ante mano

Comment: @MoisesGarcia hay distintas maneras de retornar una vista junto con las variables a utilizar ya te indico una respuesta

Comment: @ernestojimenez Nuevamente muchas gracias me se algunas de retornarlas pero aca si se me hace complicado ya que ese foreach esta en el controlador y necesito retornar justmente lo que me trae ese foreach... cuando lo hago ya por separado solo me trae un solo item no me trae todo... Una vez mas gracias por responder a ti tambien estoy algo novato en laravel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que intentas hacer puedes realizar lo siguiente, en base al codigo que entregaste simplemente me estoy haciendo una idea de las datos obtenidos

```
//Inicializo la variable vacios
$vacios = [];
//Recorro la variable $Ruc que contiene una ciertas cantidad de datos
foreah($Ruc as $key => $R){
//Se crea la variable $RucEE en donde busco en la tabla client donde el campo Ruc es igual a 
//uno de los datos que esta recorriendo el foreach
   $RucEE = client::where('Ruc',"=",$R)->first();
//Una ves obtenido los datos valido si algun $R no se encontro
   if($RucEE != null){
     //Aqui significa que uno de los datos de la variable $R se encontraron en la bd
   }else{
     echo '<b>'.$R.'</b><br>';
//Esto quiere decir que algun dato de $R no se encontro, por lo tanto toca guardarlo en el array
// se coloca array_push(variable del array, datos a guardar)
array_push($vacios,$R);
   }
//Retorno la vista junto con la variable
return view ('facturacion.create')->with([
                'vacios' => $vacios
            ]);
```

Luego en la vista puedes utilizar el nombre de la variable dereclarada en

```
->with([
                'vacios' => $vacios
            ]);
```

Yo coloque vacios, por ende en la vista debo recorrer ese array con la variable `$vacios` pero tu puedes colocar lo que quieras
Recuerda que debes recorrer con foreach esa variable desde la vista para verificar los datos que faltan

Comment: Honestamente muchisimas gracias...!! de verdad muchas gracias amigo... listo ya has dado con la solución de verdad muchisimas gracias...!! me tenia loco esto ya no comprendia como hacerlo gracias... nuevamente jejeje